# why $ \int_{X} 2g\, d\mu \le $ $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{X} \bigl(2g - |f_n -f|\bigr) d\mu$?

Tags: measure-theory

Taken from **Rudin book**

I have some confusion in inequalities given below marked in red box and blue box

[image]

**My attempt**:   $$2g  =2g$$

$$2g - 1 < 2g$$

similarly $$ 2g- |f_n| \le 2g  , n \to \infty$$

$$ 2g -|f_n -f| \le 2g$$

$$\int_{X} 2g - |f_n -f| d\mu \le \int_{X} 2g d\mu$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \int_{X} 2g - |f_n -f| d\mu \le \int_{X} 2g d\mu$$

**My  doubt** :Im confusion about inequalities $\le$. i think it should be $\ge$

why $ \int_{X} 2g d\mu \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \int_{X} 2g - |f_n -f| d\mu$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of Fatou's Lemma. Let $h_n=2g-|f_n-f|$ Since $f_n \to f$ pointwise we get $\lim \inf h_n=\lim h_n=2g$ So $\int 2g =\int \lim \inf h_n \leq \lim \inf \int h_n=\lim \int [2g-|f_n-f|]$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Fatou lemma with $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |f_n - f| = 0 $.

Then, $\int \liminf_{n \to \infty} \left(2g - |f_n - f|\right)d\mu  \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \left(\int 2g - |f_n - f|\right)d\mu$.

Comment: As you participated at that part, this is main reason that LDCT holds.